# Path Finding for execv()

Tags: c, linux, path

I'm trying to find my current PATH to use it in my execv() command but i'm stuck with figuring out how to find the path any tips ?

Comment: Why not use [`execvp()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp) or do you have a different problem?

Comment: i have to use execv()

Comment: `execvp()` (the C library function) *does* call `execv()` (the syscall). Thus, when you use `execvp()`, you *are* using `execv()` for all practical purposes. The only reason I could see for you to be forced to call `execv()` directly would be if this is homework, in which case you should be showing your work and otherwise complying with [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/14122).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the current[`PATH` variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) from your environment (see [environ(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html)) use [getenv(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html).

So code:

```
char*curpath = getenv("PATH");
if (!curpath) { fprintf(stderr, "no PATH\n"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

<sup>the lack of `PATH` is extremely unlikely</sup>

Then use [strchr(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html) to iterate on colons in `curpath`

Of course you should prefer [execvp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execvp.3.html) if allowed to use it.

To get the current [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) (but you don't need it here) use [getcwd(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getcwd.3.html).